# Could someone explain why is there a semicolon after an object name in modern C++ constructor syntax? For example, in a constructor... rd; {};

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor

I used to write a bit of c++ about 20 years ago. I need to work on some again, but things have changed. I really don't understand some of the new syntax, despite searching for it in the 4th edition of Stroustrup's c++ book. I'm using Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.3.0 Thread model: posix. In the constructor I would have expected to initialise objects with syntax like rd{}; I don't understand why the compiler wants a semicolon after the object name like rd;{};

The following code compiles and works - I just don't understand the section indicated in the comments.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

class normRand {

public:

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen;
    normal_distribution<double>  dist;

    normRand() {
          // The constructor is meant to initialise the Mersenne twister
          // random number generator with a seed from some device and then
          // use this generator to randomly select values from a standard
          // normal distribution.
      
          // Why is there a semicolon after the object name?
          // The compiler says that the object names are expressions - why?
          
          /* I DO NOT UNDERSTAND! */
          rd; {};
          gen;  {rd();};
          dist; {0.0, 1.0;};       
          /* ******************** */
    }
    
    double val() {
      return dist(gen);
    }

};

normRand myNormRand;

int main() {
    cout << myNormRand.val();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the statements inside the `/* I DO NOT UNDERSTAND! */` block do anything useful.

Comment: fwiw, the "old" variant would be `rd();` which unfortunately would have compiled, but nevertheless be equally wrong

Comment: Is your compiler using the `c++98` standard (default on macOS) and you tried to compile c++11 code but had errors and modified the code to the current contents which compile but do nothing??

Comment: That's not how constructor initialization has ever worked in C++. The initializers belong after a `:` _before_ the constructors body: `normRand() : /* initializers here, comma separated */ { /* constructor body*/ }`. The new initialization syntax has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @drescherjm they tried this https://godbolt.org/z/Ebxxa8v37 and then drew the wrong conclusion from the error message. For their defense, they just did what the message suggests

Comment: The code may compile, but it doesn't "work" if your interpretation of "work" is "initialise the members of the object".    You've obviously forgotten basics and have made wild guesses about how constructors work, and guessed completely wrong.   `rd; {};`  evaluates `rd` then discards the result.  `{}` is an empty block that does nothing.   If you want to initialise the members write the constructor with a set of initialisers BEFORE the constructor body.  For example, `normRand() : rd{}, gen{rd()}, dist{0.0, 1.0}  {}`.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler complains about doing `rd{};` because that is not something you can do in a constructor body.  `rd` has already been initialized, so trying to reinitialize it is an error.

What you should have done is used the class member initializer list to initialize the members, like this:

```cpp
class normRand {

public:

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen;
    normal_distribution<double>  dist;

    normRand() : rd{}, gen{rd}, dist{0.0, 1.0} {}
    
    double val() {
      return dist(gen);
    }

};
```

The reason `rd; {};` compiled is because `rd;` is an id expression and just evaluates to the value of `rd`, and `{}` is an empty code block followed by the empty expression of `;`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize a C++ object any place you want. For example:

```
int main()
{
    Someclass foo;
    foo{}; // wrong object already created and initialized
}
```

With classes situation is different as object declaration and initialization are in different place. But that place is special:

```
class Object {
   Someclass foo; 
public:
   Object() : foo{} // <- initialized here
   {
       // cannot be initialized here too late
   }
};
```

you cannot initialize them in constructor body, that's too late. And no these things were not changed and was that way since C++98 (except you can also use {} for initialization instead of () ).